# In Google Sheets, how to convert [2021-10-08 23:49:37] to a (-6) time zone and look like [10-October-2021, 05:49:37 PM]

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, timezone, string-formatting, spreadsheet

This includes

- The day difference
- Converting 24h to AM/PM
- Format: day-month-year, hour:minutes:seconds AM/PM
- Note: when double-clicking the original cell it's formatted as text and has (') before the text

Comment: Hi! Please don't just request others to make code, but show own research & efforts. Stack Overflow is not like a freelancer platform, 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=TEXT((A1*1)-"6:00", "dd-mmmm-yyyy, hh:mm:ss am/pm")
```

[image]

Comment: You ARE the man. Thank you for saving my day!